# How to convert two dataframes (with same cols/rows) into a dataframe of tuples?

Tags: pandas

how to convert two dataframes e.g.:

```py
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2,3], 'B': [10, 20,30]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 22,33], 'B': [110, 220, 330]})
```

into

```
     A       B
0   (1, 11) (10, 110)
1   (2, 22) (20, 220)
2   (3, 33) (30, 330)
```

I'm trying to find a pandas function instead of using a loop. This is just a dummy example and the original dataframes have many columns

Comment: updated the example to have multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is probably

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": zip(df1.A, df2.A)})
```

Much faster and simpler than the other solutions

```
def repeat_df(df, n):
    return pd.concat([df]*n, ignore_index=True)

n = 1000

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 22, 32]})

df1 = repeat_df(df1, n)
df2 = repeat_df(df2, n)
```

```
>>> %timeit df1.join(df2, lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2').apply(tuple, axis=1).to_frame('A')

36.6 ms ± 1.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).agg(tuple)

39.8 ms ± 3.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit pd.DataFrame({"A": zip(df1.A, df2.A)})

1.95 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**EDIT**

OP updated the example to work with multiple columns.
The above solution can be easily generalized

```
df = pd.DataFrame({col: zip(df1[col], df2[col]) for col in df1.columns})
```

Still much faster than the other solution. Assuming the same settings

```
>>> %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).agg(tuple)

70.3 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit pd.DataFrame({col: zip(df1[col], df2[col]) for col in df1.columns})

3.41 ms ± 389 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Using the solution, I get an error `TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()`

Comment: @mnist what version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: @mnist either way, to solve it, you just need to change `zip(df1[col], df2[col])` to `list(zip(df1[col], df2[col]))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.join`:

```py
df1.join(df2, lsuffix='1', rsuffix='2').apply(tuple, axis=1).to_frame('A')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `concat` both then use `groupby.agg` on the index. Using this method would align columns and `groupby` identical index.

```
print(pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).agg(tuple)) 
         A
0  (1, 11)
1  (2, 22)
2  (3, 32)
```

that said, in this specific case, maybe using a list comprehension is faster

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':[(a1, a2) for a1, a2 in zip(df1['A'], df2['A'])]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas [pd.itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) for converting dataframe into pandas tuples after merging two dataframes.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
tuples = df.itertuples()
```